# PHP - Converting Seconds to Minutes discrepancy

Tags: php, date, datetime-conversion

I'm running into a discrepancy with either my conversion of an integer into defined Minutes.

```
<?php
$seconds = 269;
echo date("G:i:s", $seconds);
// result: 0:04:29
?>
```

I figured I'd double check on some sites to see if the conversion is correct:

Here's one I found:
http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/conversions/time.php

The result returned is: 4.4833333333333

Example 1 returns: **0:04:29**
Example 2 returns: **4.4833333333333**

I'm confused about this.
What am I missing here.  Am I using the `date()` function incorrectly?

Comment: Where is the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `date()`. it expects to be provided with a PHP timestamp, which is number of seconds since midnight, Jan 1/1970. It will "work" for small timestamp values, but will get increasingly wrong as you pass in "larger" timestamps, as you will be dealing with months/days/years in 1970, plus leapyears, etc...

As for the conversion, what's wrong with it? 4.48333... is 4 full minutes, and 0.483333 is simply 29/60.

Comment: I placed the discrepancy a little more evident this time.  The PHP is returning a resule less than the 2nd conversion example.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : You're right. I wasn't looking at it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class for time calculation:

#### Code:

```
$start = new DateTime;
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('+269 seconds');
$diff = $start->diff($end);
print_r($diff);
```

#### Output:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 4
    [s] => 29
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
```

As you can see in output, you have all the info you need. To access it, just use `$diff->i` for minutes, `$diff->s` for seconds etc.